# Android SDK 2.0 supports A2DP and AVRCP or not

Tags: android, android-emulator

Can anyone let me know Android SDK 2.0 supports A2DP and AVRCP or not.

Regards,
John

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Bluetooth page on the Android Open Source Project website](http://source.android.com/porting/bluetooth.html) A2DP 1.2 and AVRCP 1.0 have been supported since Android version 1.5 (Cupcake).